# iOS Build Failed at compile time with issue "failed to find a suitable device for the type SimDeviceType"

Tags: ios, xcode, compilation

I am getting following compile time issue when running the app with Xcode 10.3 beta 2 on iPad Air, I am getting the below issue.

```
Failed to find a suitable device for the type SimDeviceType : com.apple.dt.Xcode.IBSimDeviceType.iPad-2x with runtime SimRuntime : 10.3 (14E5239d) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-10-3
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just a heads up - ulsc's answer below is what is happening here. `sudo killall -9 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService` does the trick

Answer (score 341, accepted):

It seems like the old simulator process remained open in the background during an XCode update.

Simply running

`sudo killall -9 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService`

in terminal may solve the problem.
There shouldn't be a need for cleaning the project and/or build folder.

Comment: Correct. This problem appears after updating to Xcode 10.3. The above command solved the problem. No clean build folder is needed. Before the command is executed, 4 processes of simulator services are running, even though no simulator is running. Restarting computer works as well, as it will end all related simulator services during reboot.

Comment: Same here. Tnx :)

Comment: Same problem while upgrading from Xcode 10.3 to Xcode 10.4. Thanks for your hint! :)

Comment: Yes, please mark it as the correct answer or at least pin it at the top if possible. Thank You It helped to solve my problem

Comment: or just reboot macOS with same effect, worked on 2 Macs.

Comment: Same issue when upgraded to xcode 10.3. it worked. Thanks!

Comment: If every stackoverflow answer was as helpful as this one, that would be ok with me!

Comment: I personally Marked this as an answer, thanks mate.

Answer (score 20):

If you quit Xcode and still get the same error, then try clean (command + shift + option + k) and select option "Clean" in popup. Repeat this 2 to 3 times. It works in my case.

Comment: This seems to be the golden rule when it comes to Xcode - repeat the same solution many times and eventually it works.

Answer (score 7):

I was experiencing the same problem. In my case, I had launched the Simulator from a previous version of Xcode prior to building. The problem persisted when I quit the simulator, but restarting Xcode solved it for me.

Comment: Make sure to also restart the Metro bundler if it's running.

Answer (score 6):

I just ran into the same issue on the latest Xcode 10.3 (10G8).  Had to perform about 4 or 5 full project cleans, and bounce the box, before I could compile again.  I wish Apple would get this fixed.

Comment: Same thing here, I just upgraded to Xcode 10.3 and the error resisted to disappear until I restarted my computer :<

Comment: Restarting computer solved this issue... (Xcode 10.3)

Comment: Me too (XCode 10.3)

Answer (score 2):

I simply had to disconnect the iPad I had connected to my Mac. For some reason that was messing with the way Xcode was compiling.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that solved it for me was the following:

1. Clear the `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes` folder
2. Restart Xcode
3. Clear the project
4. Run the project

Answer (score 0):

I solve this by launching the simulator first, Xcode will pass the build.

then run the project on the device.

hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

If you are running multiple versions of xcode, you should check `xcode-select -p` to ensure you are using the correct version of xcode and compiler.  If not, use `xcode-select -s { correct xcode path }` to set the correct version of xcode.

Comment: I am using Xcode 8.3 and Xcode 9. When I input in terminal  `xcode-select -p` I get `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer` . How can I fix this? In Applications folder I have the name Xcode for Xcode9 and | Xcode8 for Xcode 8

Comment: Inside of the applications folder you probably manually put it there.  If you installed through the App Store, that version will be /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer.  I do not believe there can be two installed app store versions at the same time.  If you want to switch, then you need to manually point to the other one, which as I said believe was manually put there.  So the same thing still applies where you `xcode-select -s { Xcode8 or 9 }`

Answer (score 0):

Getting same issue but after an hour getting success to fix this issue there is xcode problem. So please reopen your xcode and then clean your project.. or use short cut command for clear (command + shift + option + k)