# Xcode project: Build Failed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos

I tried to build my new project, but when I click build, the build fails every time.

I tried deleting my project and made it again, but it did not help anyway.

Warning

```
:-1: Capabilities for MyFirstApp may not function correctly because its entitlements use a placeholder team ID. To resolve this, select a development team in the build settings editor. (in target 'MyFirstApp')
```

Error

```
~/MyFirstApp/Base.lproj/LaunchScreen.storyboard:-1: Failed to find or create execution context for description '<IBCocoaTouchPlatformToolDescription: 0x7fc3a9a03e10> System content for IBCocoaTouchFramework-ElevenAndLater <IBScaleFactorDeviceTypeDescription: 0x7fc3a9a141a0> scaleFactor=2x'. These intermediate objects were non-nil: (

~/MyFirstApp/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard:-1: Failed to find or create execution context for description '<IBCocoaTouchPlatformToolDescription: 0x7fc982cd0ca0> System content for IBCocoaTouchFramework-ElevenAndLater <IBScaleFactorDeviceTypeDescription: 0x7fc982cb9cd0> scaleFactor=2x'. These intermediate objects were non-nil: (
```

These are the error messages that Xcode showed me. The project name was 'MyFirstApp' and I cut some file paths on that error messages. So how can I build this project?

Comment: Can you build _any_ new project? Just make a plain vanilla Single View app straight from the template and try to build it. Can you?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know how to make a plain vanilla Single View app because I'm new to iOS development. I made my project by Create a new Xcode project - iOS, Single View App - ... and so on. As soon as I created the project, I built it right away.

Comment: Yep, good. Can you build that?

Comment: I built that right away and the error messages came out like in the question.

Comment: OK your installation of Xcode is hosed. Is this a new installation or did you update?

Comment: I updated Xcode via settings because the build kept failing. But the result was the same.

Comment: did you try my solution ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS Build Failed at compile time with issue "failed to find a suitable device for the type SimDeviceType"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42823160/ios-build-failed-at-compile-time-with-issue-failed-to-find-a-suitable-device-fo)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this in terminal:

```
sudo killall -9 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService
```