# iOS - Build fails with Xcode 10.3 and iOS target

Tags: ios, swift, xcode10.3

I have upgraded the Xcode to 10.3.
My all simulators gone and when I am trying to build then getting the following error on compile time.

> **System content for IBCocoaTouchFramework-ElevenAndLater 
>   scaleFactor=2x'.**

Comment: Have you seen this https://stackoverflow.com/a/57256188/7629882 ?

Comment: I had the same. Close Xcode, restart the computer and all was back to normal.

Comment: @ArashEtemad thanks it worked!!!.
You save my day.

Comment: I will appreciate if you upvote my answer